# After submitting a POST form open a new window showing the result

Tags: javascript, html, post

[JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/133925) shows you how to submit a form that you create via POST in JavaScript. Below is my modified code.

```
var form = document.createElement("form");

form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "test.jsp");

var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");  

hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "id");
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "bob");
form.appendChild(hiddenField);
document.body.appendChild(form); // Not entirely sure if this is necessary          
form.submit();
```

What I would like to do is open the results in a new window. I am currently using something like this to open a page in a new window:

```
onclick = window.open(test.html, '', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
```

Comment: Note that `document.body.appendChild(form)` **is** necessary, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/42053775/58241

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Add

```
<form target="_blank" ...></form>
```

or

```
form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
```

to your form's definition.

Comment: Remember to add the attribute id to the form element, otherwise this doesn't work in Safari browser even though the popup blocker is turned off. <form **id="popupForm"** target="_blank" ...></form>

Comment: @Naren, i'm facing issues in Safari Browser and (iphone devices) while submitting the form via JS. i'm getting "network connection lost" while posting is happening. if i try to pause the debugger for some "x" seconds and release debugger then its working fine. could you please guide me on this.

Comment: form.setAttribute is exactly what I was looking for.  In my case, I only wanted the results in a new window in certain circumstances, so setting target inside the form was a no-go.

Answer (score 135):

If you want to create and submit your form from Javascript as is in your question and you want to create popup window with custom features I propose this solution (I put comments above the lines i added):

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "test.jsp");

// setting form target to a window named 'formresult'
form.setAttribute("target", "formresult");

var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");              
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "id");
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "bob");
form.appendChild(hiddenField);
document.body.appendChild(form);

// creating the 'formresult' window with custom features prior to submitting the form
window.open('test.html', 'formresult', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');

form.submit();
```

Comment: +1 Better than the accepted answer, since it actually puts the result in the popup with the options the OP wanted.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on IE - it creates a new window with the specified attributes and then loads the results in another new window, leaving the previous window empty.

Comment: I've added a new line to make it work in IE - it's not nice, but it works. Firefox (which doesn't support readyState) will never have "loading" set.

Comment: @mjaggard: What did you add? It might be worth suggesting an edit to this answer.

Comment: I did suggest an edit but I can't see it still.

while (newWind.document.readyState == "loading") {}

Comment: 1. Does this work across all browsers?   2. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp claims that the target attribute of the ```form``` element is deprecated.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda As far as I can tell, `target` attribute on `form` element is **not deprecated** in [HTML 4.01 Transitional](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/present/frames.html#h-16.3) and apparently is to stay in [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-form-element.html#the-form-element).

Comment: A warning: I had to attach my form to the document body before this would work (in FF 17). Creating a fragment and trying to sumbit it didn't work.

Comment: Remember to add the attribute id to the form element, otherwise this doesn't work in Safari browser even though the popup blocker is turned off. <form **id="popupForm"** target="_blank" ...></form>

Comment: @MarkoDumic Little late to ask but .. i had the exact same problem and tried your code above. i am getting two pop ups intead of one. one for form submit (with actual url ) and another for window.open with test.html (tht gives 404). would you know why would that happen?

Comment: Also wanted to add that  ours is a citrix based application so only IE . not sure if that makes a difference

Answer (score 8):

```
var urlAction = 'whatever.php';
var data = {param1:'value1'};

var $form = $('<form target="_blank" method="POST" action="' + urlAction + '">');
$.each(data, function(k,v){
    $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="' + k + '" value="' + v + '">');
});
$form.submit();
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or do you still need to `.append` the close form tag?

Comment: I think this is incomplete after append the form you should remove it for a best practice.

Comment: @theJollySin: By calling jQuery on the tag, it will turn into a real DOM element and would be closed when inserted into the DOM.

Comment: I think there is a missing appendTo('body') and last line should be written as:
`$form.appendTo('body').submit();`

Answer (score 4):

Simplest working solution for flow window (tested at Chrome):

```
<form action='...' method=post target="result" onsubmit="window.open('','result','width=800,height=400');">
    <input name="..">
    ....
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this basic method:

1)

```
<input type=”image” src=”submit.png”> (in any place)
```

2)

```
<form name=”print”>
<input type=”hidden” name=”a” value=”<?= $a ?>”>
<input type=”hidden” name=”b” value=”<?= $b ?>”>
<input type=”hidden” name=”c” value=”<?= $c ?>”>
</form>
```

3)

```
<script>
$(‘#submit’).click(function(){
    open(”,”results”);
    with(document.print)
    {
        method = “POST”;
        action = “results.php”;
        target = “results”;
        submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

Works!

Comment: thats with jquery ! he asks for pure JS