# open a new window with post values enhancements

Tags: javascript, post, window, new-operator

```
    var projectWindow;
    function btnNew_Click() {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("target", "projectWindow");
        form.setAttribute("method", "post");
        form.setAttribute("action", "MySite.aspx");

        document.body.appendChild(form);

        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("id", "hiddenValue");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "ID");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "/*get value from javascript*/");

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);

        //Below line I added to fix the new input text field that was visible
        document.getElementById("hiddenValue").style.visibility = 'hidden';

        form.submit();

        //The below line i added to give focus if another window is created
        // The below code does not work
        projectWindow.focus();

        //I also tried this:
        form.focus();
}
```

My problem in the above code that i obtained from the thread:
[Javascript Post on Form Submit open a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178964/javascript-post-on-form-submit-open-a-new-window)

is that there is an input field that is shown at the client that I cant hide, except for the first time with the line I added (maybe this is about many values return from the method getElementbyId).

The second problem is that I want to set focus in the newly created or reloaded window, currently it is only working with the new window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding it to the `onload` of the new window:

```
projectWindow.onload = function(){projectWindow.focus()};
```

Didn't test this code, hope this helps!
Oh! and to create a hidden input, do this:

```
var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
```

Also, `getElementById` should not return many values, just one! If it does return more than one, there is something wrong.

Comment: the onload things is not working,
how can i add the onload to the newly loaded window instead of the code at the opener page.

Comment: It appears that the problem that i had was related to the firefox security rules. This worked perfectly in Internet Explorer

Answer (score 0):

To add on Victor's answer. The function `btnNew_Click` always create a new form element.

You either have to check for it's existence and not recreate or destroy it after submitting it.

Comment: Im already checking for the availability of the new window:

form.setAttribute("target", "projectWindow");

can u tell me how if this is the intended thing, if not please let me know what can i do to set it right.

Comment: I'm refering to the form created by document.createElement, not the window.