# Results page in other window

Tags: javascript, php, forms, dom-events

I have this simple form:

```
<form method="post" action".">
<input type="text" name="title">
<input type="submit" name"send">
</form>
```

I want that when a user click on submit, then will be open another window of browser with the results. Is it possible?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178964/javascript-post-on-form-submit-open-a-new-window

Comment: @Artefacto: Not really, that question is using Javascript to do the post. Although the question is tagged Javacript, I think it's just a normal form submission (@xRobot: Right?).

Comment: You don't need Javascript for this at all (see andr's answer). Did you have a reason you actively *wanted* to use Javascript for this, rather than a built-in mechanism? Or did you just not know there *was* a built-in mechanism?

Comment: Fair enough. The accepted answer provides a non-javascript mechanism (the one andr gave) though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to open a new window:

```
<form method="post" action="..." target="_blank">
...
```

If you want a popup or lightbox or anything scripty:

```
<form method="post" action="..." onsubmit="yourFunction()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<form method="post" action"thepagetodisplay.php">
<input type="text" name="title" id="title">
<input type="submit" name"send">
</form>
```

on thepagetodisplay.php

```
extract($_POST);
echo $title;
```