# Open page in new window without popup blocking

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Hope you can help a bit here...
I have a form that translate a word in a field, populate the field with the translated term and then do submit action all in one submit button.

the submit is being made by jquery.
problem is the target page is being blocked as all 3 major browsers treat it as popup,
Do you know how to let it open just as a new tab or new window ?
I don't want to set the target as _self as I want people to have my site open as well.

I believe the problem is in this string:

```
document.forms.form1.submit();
```

but I also know there should be a way to rephrase it so the target won't be treated as a popup.

this is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function transle() {
  $('#transbox').sundayMorningReset();
  $('#transbox input[type=button]').click(function(evt) {
    $.sundayMorning(
      $('#transbox input[type=text]').val(), {
        source: '',
        destination: 'ZH',
        menuLeft: evt.pageX,
        menuTop: evt.pageY
      },
      function(response) {
        $('#transbox input[type=text]').val(response.translation);

        //document.getElementById("form1").submit();
        document.forms.form1.submit();

      }
    );
  });
});

</script>
```

and this is the form:

```
<table id="transbox" name="transbox" width="30px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <form action="custom-page" method="get" name="form1" target="_blank" id="form1">

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="q" name="q" type="text" class="search_input" onFocus="if (this.value == 'Evening dress') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Evening dress';}" value="Evening dress" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Find" style="color: #333; width: 157px; font-weight:bold"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </form>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

I have tried all of these strings to submit:

```
document.getElementById("form1").submit();
document.forms.form1.submit();
form1.submit();
```

all ends up with the target being popup blocked.
please, is there any other way I should do the code to not let it popup ?

maybe should use the onsubmit to make jQuery ?
someone knows how ?

Comment: Does it work with the popup blocker off. Also you can use $("#form1").submit(); to submit the form instead of document.forms.form1.submit();

Comment: yes, when I approve popups there is no problem. also if it is submited by the submit button and not jquery is nt regarded as popup.

Comment: Try and call the $("button").click() on the submit button.

Comment: and $("#form1").submit();  didn't do anything...

Comment: Check out


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178964/javascript-post-on-form-submit-open-a-new-window

Comment: @D. Mathis , not sure how to do that. can you show me in the code ?

Comment: Hi, I have checked the additional js included and I fount that this code:   $.fn.sundayMorningReset = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
    $(this).unbind('.sundayMorning');       
  });
 } is the one causing the  form1.submit(); not to work, do you have any clue to why ?

Comment: There's a reason browsers started implementing pop-up blockers. Instead of fighting it, perhaps rethink having a pop-up at all.

Answer (score 93):

A browser will only open a tab/popup without the popup blocker warning if the command to open the tab/popup comes from a [trusted event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events). That means the user has to actively click somewhere to open a popup.

In your case, the user performs a click so you have the trusted event. You do lose that trusted context, however, by performing the Ajax request. Your success handler does not have that event anymore. The only way to circumvent this is to perform a synchronous Ajax request which will block your browser while it runs, but will preserve the event context.

In jQuery this should do the trick:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'http://yourserver/',
 data: 'your image',
 success: function(){window.open(someUrl);},
 async: false
});
```

Here is your answer: [Open new tab without popup blocker after ajax call on user click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885676/open-new-tab-without-popup-blocker-after-ajax-call-on-user-click)

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work anymore. The new window doesn't open and the web console shows the error: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/"

Comment: This solution works on my browser and shows the above as a warning.

Comment: works, but I got warning: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: async:false is the solution for me , thank you

Answer (score 23):

This is the only one that actually worked for me in all the browsers

`let newTab = window.open();
 newTab.location.href = url;`

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

As a general rule, pop up blockers target windows that launch without user interaction. Usually a click event *can* open a window without it being blocked. (unless it's a really bad popup blocker)

Try launching after a click event

Answer (score 7):

PS> I posted this answer on a related question. Here's how I got round the issue of my async ajax request losing the trusted context:

I opened the popup directly on the users click, directed the url to `about:blank` and got a handle on that window. You could probably direct the popup to a 'loading' url while your ajax request is made

`var myWindow = window.open("about:blank",'name','height=500,width=550');`

Then, when my request is successful, I open my callback url in the window

```
function showWindow(win, url) {
     win.open(url,'name','height=500,width=550');
}
```

Comment: this works if you want to open a new window anyway. what if the open is conditional based on the callback. we would have to call `.close()` and it would create an open/close flash.... any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

For the Submit button, add this code and then set your form target="newwin"

```
onclick=window.open("about:blank","newwin")
```

Answer (score 0):

My case was a little more complex, due to the fact that my initial user interaction was

- a button click
- which triggered an event-handler
- which called a method
- that returned a promise
- which contained an ajax call
- and just when this promise was fulfilled actually should open the url.

The only way I got it to work correctly was in two steps, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33216257/19909565):

```
function someFunctionThatsCalledByUserClick(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        let newTab = window.open();     // <-- always open new tab
        return ajax_wrapper_func().then( data => {
            let url = extract_url(data);
            newTab.location.href = url;     // <-- set the url
            resolve();
        }).catch(e=>{
            newTab.close();     // <-- remove the tab on errors
            reject(e);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function openLinkNewTab (url){
    $('body').append('<a id="openLinkNewTab" href="' + url + '" target="_blank"><span></span></a>').find('#openLinkNewTab span').click().remove();
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Tried this quickly in scratchpad (Firefox) and (as expected) this triggered my popup blocker. 
`openLinkNewTab('https://ddg.gg');`