# Trying to open multiple windows in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to open multiple urls on click of a button. Am testing on Chrome
PS: I am doing this for myself. I am just trying to open all urls which i want to read daily in the morning. I don't want to waste time clicking on each url for example. Not sure if javascript is the right tool to build such functionality or not
Wrote the following code and it's not opening, just opening the first and the last url

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Shopping</title>
        <script>               

            function Software()
            {
                window.open("http://forums.asp.net/", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
                window.open("http://www.joelonsoftware.com/", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
                window.open("http://blog.cwa.me.uk/", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
                window.open("http://www.lifehacker.com/", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
                window.open("http://www.Theverge.com", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
                window.open("http://www.hanselman.com/", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
                window.open("http://www.goodreads.com", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
                window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>            
        <a href="http://www.channel9.msdn.com/" onclick="Software()">
            Software / Programming 
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser do you use? Some browser may block pop-ups.

Comment: @Kiril Testing on Chrome.

Comment: I would say 90% of modern browsers will block this. Opening so many windows to different URLs is only going to look suspicious (and to be honest it is suspicious). You also have no control over when the browser will prevent this. Put simply, **don't do this**. No body ever likes this functionality

Comment: Most browsers are trying to prevent this sort of behavior because of misuse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow window.open to open new window and not popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643040/allow-window-open-to-open-new-window-and-not-popup)

Comment: @Liam is right, it's not a good practice. It could be done with the help of adding `"_black"` as a second parameter but chrome will block 7 of 8 pop-ups.

Comment: Would the browser still block these if there was a timeout before each one?

Comment: @jfriend00 I am doing this for myself. I am just trying to open all urls which i want to read daily in the morning. I don't want to waste time clicking on each url for example. Not sure if javascript is the right tool to build such functionality or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing this for yourself, Chrome has a feature when you right click on a folder of bookmarks that offers you the choice to "Open All Bookmarks In a New Window".

The other options that might avoid the popup blocker logic are to write a small browser plugin or to use the command line to start an instance of the browser with a bunch of URLs.

Answer (score 4):

Give your windows unique names:

```
function Software() {
  window.open("http://forums.asp.net/", "w1", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
  window.open("http://www.joelonsoftware.com/", "w2", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
  window.open("http://blog.cwa.me.uk/", "w3", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
  window.open("http://www.lifehacker.com/", "w4", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
  window.open("http://www.Theverge.com", "w5", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
  window.open("http://www.hanselman.com/", "w6", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
  window.open("http://www.goodreads.com", "w7", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
  window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com", "w8", "status=1,toolbar=1,menubar=1");
}
```

Note that these links will open as actual windows, not tabs.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9xBv7/

Comment: I can see only the first url being opened in the demo

Comment: Multiple windows are open on top of each other - move the top window, you will see the rest

Comment: This triggers the default popup blocker in chrome so that only the first URL opens in a new window.  All other URLs are not opened and are listed as being blocked from opening the popup blocker's UI.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try just setting your home page to open all those when your browser opens instead.

[Link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/zi__buaH-HE)

Or you could embed them in IFrames in a page as well. That way you don't have to open a bunch of different windows.