# Change one tab multiple times with an extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, tabs, window

I want to build a chrome extension that will search 30 different things up on the same tab. I tried the `location.replace` method and the `_self` method but nothing happened. However, when I tried `window.open`, it did work. This only opens a new window once, but I want it to open multiple times. How would I do this?

This is my code so far (`arr` is an array with some words):

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}
for(var i = 0; i<30; i++) {
  window.open('https://www.bing.com/search?q='+arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]);
  sleep (1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it giving a different name to each one:

```
window.open(url, `${Math.random()}`);
```

[Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: This opens up one window, how do I make it open more than one?

Comment: This opens up several tabs in the same window

Comment: I think you are looking for for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607983/trying-to-open-multiple-windows-in-javascript