# $window to open multiple links blocked by pop up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to use Angular's $window to open multiple links at once? The browser seem to block the pop up, is there anywhere to overcome that issue?

`http://plnkr.co/edit/m8m2I9dqE2kF1H1nzxJT?p=preview`

```
  $scope.links = [
    {'link':'www.google.com'},
    {'link':'www.yahoo.com'},
    {'link':'www.bing.com'}
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

So yes. The problem is that the windows are being opened to another domain -- so the browser will block the windows. The solution is to open the window at a page in your domain, and pass the url you want to go to and then have that page redirect to the page.

http://plnkr.co/edit/nAfQ4oHyCC22oSCFqMpH?p=info

Comment: Interesting usage of the search method and then redirect

Comment: how bout multiple links?

Comment: I tried multiple links but the first open in the new windows but not others, others pop up instead..

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the post and update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue. After dark days when spammers used popups for displaying advertisements, `window.open()` is blocked.

**Pleas read**

- [Allow window.open to open new window and not popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643040/allow-window-open-to-open-new-window-and-not-popup)
- [Open page in new window without popup blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139103/open-page-in-new-window-without-popup-blocking)