# open multiple links in a new windows at once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to avoid the link to be blocked by browser popup?

my demo work but it only open the first link, I wonder.. I used foreach..

http://plnkr.co/edit/m8m2I9dqE2kF1H1nzxJT

Comment: Why do you reopen the same question with a new user? [$window to open multiple links blocked by pop up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355471/window-to-open-multiple-links-blocked-by-pop-up)

Answer (score 0):

Added `value, key` to CB function args and used that to get at the link value, also added the window name attribute telling open function to open blank window each time:

```
angular.forEach($scope.links, function(value, key){
    $window.open("link.html/?" + value.link, '_blank');
});
```

`$scope.links.link` was returning "undefined" in that location.

Comment: using redirect work fine but the links after first link pop up, not in opening in the new windows.. arrhhhjjjjjj

Comment: I get three windows opening when I use Firefox browser.

Comment: @bloodyknucles, work well in FF, but not in chrome :(