# why window.open() dont work directly in a <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, browser

It seems that the function window.open() of javascript doesn't work directly in a script tag it must be inside a function and that function must be called why is that and thanx?

Example :

```
//Not working
<div>
<button> Click here </button>
</div>
<script>
var w = window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
</script>

//Working
<div>
<button onclick=n()> Click here </button>
</div>
<script>
function n(){
var w = window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Because a lot of people abused it to show irrelevant ads... at best.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Do you have your popup blocker on? If you turn off the popup blocker, it should work as expected (http://jsfiddle.net/m3hj1xqu/). Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643040

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.open` will work in and out of function. But there is a problem when you are calling it without the presence of **actual user action**. The browser's popup blocker will come in the way and prevent it from opening the new window/tab.

You will see this warning in your browser.

You can make it work either by disabling the popup blocker.

You can also make it work by adding the call to `window.open` in actual user action, for example:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com/");
});
</script>
```

It will work when you will click the window.

Comment: @pinturic his right bro it's working it was just the popup blocker

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the DOM isn't ready yet. Try:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
    window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com/");
});
```

Also, this might be getting caught by your browser's pop-up blocker.

Answer (score 0):

In this code "w" is null and no window is opened because you can open a new window only as a result of a human action (like a click on a button).

```
<div>
<button> Click here </button>
</div>
<script>
var w = window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
</script>
```

This is done specifically to avoid sites opening random new windows without the consent of the user.

Comment: Half correct. The code is still wrong since you need the call to be made from the user gesture's event. You are currently doing it way before the button gets even painted.

Comment: But the code is the same with the function or without it so whats the difference between executing it inside a function and directly?

Comment: @Kaiido this is what I am saying! I agree with you! you cannot open a new window without a gesture. That's why the second code with the onclick is working!

Comment: @Hamdi no! it is different the first code is evaluated sequentially in the html so the window.open  is ignored because is not coming from a gesture.

Comment: Yes but your code is not showing it. You'd need to call it from the click event handler. Here you are putside and not listening to anything.

Comment: yeah i think i understand now so the compiler is ignoring it because it's not been triggered by an event is that it?

Comment: @Kaiido My code is copy/paste of the previous code and I was explaining why it is not working

Comment: @pinturic thanx bro i get it now

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you've just assigned the open() function to a variable; you haven't actually invoked (triggered) the function in any way.

You can either do this by attaching an event listener to the button, so that the function gets triggered on click:

```js
const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com/");
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Click here</button>
</div>
```

Or trigger the function automatically on load:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com/");
};
```

NB: neither of my examples will open a new window here due to security policies.
 They'll work in application.

Comment: How is `window.open(...)` not invoking anything?