# Why the behaviour of anchor is different when trigger click using js and actual click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, anchor, window.open

I am trying to open a new tab using js.

```
$("#hello").attr("href", "https://www.youtube.com/");

setTimeout(function() {
  $("#hello")[0].click()
}, 1000);
```

```html
<a id="hello" target="_blank">Hello</a>
```

The problem with this approach is that a browser is asking user permission to open new tab. But when I click on that `<a>` tag, a browser is opening new tab without asking permission from user.

Why does this type of behavior happen?

Fiddle link:- https://jsfiddle.net/90chntz4/5/

I try this one also:- [Allow window.open to open new window and not popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643040/allow-window-open-to-open-new-window-and-not-popup)

but It is not working.

How can I open new tab without asking permission from user?

Comment: This is a feature of most browsers to prevent malicious websites from opening popups. New tabs can only be opened as a response to user input.

Comment: @Turnip is there any way that I can open popup without permission? And how browser detect that it is actual click or js click trigger?

Comment: I hope not. If you find a way you should report it as a bug.

Comment: it is working fine for me

Comment: if popup is not blocked then code will execute same