# URL in new browser window does not show any controls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, zk

I am trying to open a URL in a new window.
The URL is opened in a new window but without any Menu and navigation controls.

[image: JS Code to open URL in new Window]

[image: URL opened in new TAB]

> JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Sahil_Gupta/nfuehqv1/2/

**I am using JAVA and ZK in backend and using Script to run the code as:**

```
    Script jsScriptInitializer = new Script();
    String js = "window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=yes');";     
    jsScriptInitializer.setContent(js);
    jsScriptInitializer.setDefer(true);
    jsScriptInitializer.setParent(event.getTarget().getParent().getParent());
```

I need all the navigation and menu controls as usual when I open a URL in another window.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Why not simple `window.open('https://www.google.com')`?  This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14643184/15273968) may help.

Comment: It opens in a new Tab. I need to open in new window.

Comment: @SahilGupta are you trying to open a new chrome window instead of popup? If so its not possible with javascript. you can instantiate new chrome instance by java.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work as desired in browsers other than Chrome. There has been an ongoing bug in Chrome which has turned into a feature request. You can read about it at: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82522

As of Jan 2022, there is still no way to open a Seperate window with the standard toolbars.  However, if you can accept the new window being in the form of a tab rather than a separate window, simply eliminating the third argument will open as a fully featured tab.

```js
// open a new tab
window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
```

Comment: I can see it working for other websites. How does it work for them?

Comment: Which websites are you referring to?

Comment: Any general website where chrome shows its own context menu to 'open link in new window'. I don't care if it's done by javascript or by any other language how can it be done successfully?