# How open link in new window in Opera12

Tags: javascript, html, opera

How to open link in new window in Opera 12 (Mobile Classic) with default option "Ignore unrequest popup".

This methods don't work:

```
//1
window.open('http://mylink', '_blank') 

//2
<a href="javascript:window.open('http://mylink');"> Open </a>

//3
<a href="http://mylink" target="_blank">Click</a>
```

Method in this link 
[Open new tab without popup blocker after ajax call on user click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885676/open-new-tab-without-popup-blocker-after-ajax-call-on-user-click) is not very nice (I don't want to send one more ajax request)

Comment: `<a href="http://mylink" target="_blank">Click</a>`

Comment: Is the user clicking on the link or are you using code to open it up without a user action? Pop up blockers will block it. Either have users add your domain to the safe list or you are going to have to figure out a way to do what you want without a pop up or give the user a notification the window was blocked.

Comment: @epascarello http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885676/open-new-tab-without-popup-blocker-after-ajax-call-on-user-click

Comment: @epascarello i must open link by User clicking. (user action)

Comment: So that code should work with a click unless you are delaying the window opening....

Comment: @epascarello but Google open extend links at this browser...so that possible)

Comment: *"Google open extend links"* I have no clue what that means

Comment: @epascarello google.com open links at new window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64790/discussion-between-geray-suinov-and-epascarello).