# how to make window.open (url) is not in a pop up windows

Tags: javascript, php

open in new tab but allow by popup blocker.
Anyone can open this url if his browser setting is popup block is not allowed

```
window.open('url',);
```

Comment: Which browser you use??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open new tab without popup blocker after ajax call on user click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885676/open-new-tab-without-popup-blocker-after-ajax-call-on-user-click)

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pop-blocker-settings-exceptions-troubleshooting

Comment: without allow pop up block open a window.open('url').

Comment: Why can't you just let the user click an anchor to open the new tab? Then you would not have to worry about popup blocking. Or fetch the content from the url and place it into the active window.

Comment: i want to use this where form autosubmit and open in a new tab.

Comment: I use <form action="" target="_blank"> Can this is also a pop up or not...In chrome this shows a popup block

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Its like bribing the cops. Majorly popup blockers block script-initiated pop-up windows. Popup blocker can hence be avoided if it's a user action. You can bind an event with button click which might work in most cases. So wherever you are doing your window.open() make sure its initiated by user. You can also consider opening the page with a modal or [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)