# How can I open a link in a new tab? Using JavaScript or jQuery. Without the browser alert of pop-up blocked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open a new tab using JavaScript or jQuery.

I tried this code:

```
window.open("myurl", '_blank');
```

But browser gives me alert for pop-up blocked.

I have to open new tab without pop-up blocked alert.

Each and every client can't allow pop-up.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: That's just your browser security. No way around this. ( apart from lowering your security )

Comment: Try searching before asking a question please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: click on the popup blocker and then just check the _always allowed popup from...._ option.

Comment: @Jai Each and every client can't allow pop-up. so can i  achive this without popup blocker. when we are writing some html code like anchor tag with target is blank then it opens new tab without popup blocker.

Answer (score 6):

try this,

```
$('#myButton').click(function () {
    var redirectWindow = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
    redirectWindow.location;
});
```

working js fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/safeeronline/70kdacL4/2/

working js fiddle for ajax window open  http://jsfiddle.net/safeeronline/70kdacL4/1/

Answer (score 5):

The only way to overcome this is to perform a synchronous Ajax request which will block your browser while it runs, but will preserve the event context.
This will help--->
[Open new tab without popup blocker after ajax call on user click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885676/open-new-tab-without-popup-blocker-after-ajax-call-on-user-click)

Here is the sample code for you --->

```
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>Works without warning in all browsers:</td>
        <td><input type="button" onclick="performSyncronousRequest()" value="Syncronous request"/><td>
    </tr>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Scipt--->

```
/**
* This method will give open the popup without a warning.
*/
function performSyncronousRequest() {
    $.ajax({
     url: '/echo/html',
     data: {},
     success: function(){
         window.open('http://www.w3schools.com');
     },
     async: false
    });
}
```

Heres the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/23JNw/80/

Comment: can you elaborate your explanation or write some code for me?

Comment: You can checkout the code.Works like a gem.Cheers :)

Comment: i am not using ajax. i want to redirect on new page at the time of page load. so in jquery ready block i had written `window.open("myurl", '_blank');` this code but it shows me pop-up blocker

Comment: This is the only workaround to open a path without popup(working cross browser).Using ajax is easy huhh.You can embed an ajax call in your webpage :)Cheers

Comment: i created fiddle but not working for me can you suggest changes. [ http://jsfiddle.net/23JNw/81/ ] (http://jsfiddle.net/23JNw/81/)

Comment: You will have to include this ajax call on the action you want to open a new tab(in my case its button click);or if you want to open it on load of some web page include this ajax call on load event of that webpage.

Answer (score 3):

```
var win = window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
if(win){
    //Browser has allowed it to be opened
    win.focus();
}else{
    //Broswer has blocked it
    alert('Please allow popups for this site');
}
```

Comment: i don't want to display popup blocker. so without popup blocker can i achive this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514698/bypass-popup-blocker-on-window-open-when-jquery-event-preventdefault-is-set

Comment: can you cross check my code. it gives me pop-up blocker. [http://jsfiddle.net/23JNw/81/](http://jsfiddle.net/23JNw/81/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.preview', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("Are You Sure?"))
    {
        var daoGroup = $("#daoGroup").val();
        if (daoGroup === undefined && daoGroup === null) {
            alert("Select DAO Groups");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Act on the event */
            var data = $(".frmContent").serialize();
            var url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>reportViewPrint/sailorNominalRoll/htmlPreview';
            window.open(url+'?'+ data, '_blank');
        }
    }
});
```