# Opening a new browser popup through js doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, redirect, popup

I would like to redirect users through **JS** with opening of a new browser popup (in **Chrome/FF/Safari and IE**), because after the click on the button was done I have to **wait for the result** of a response with the **correct url**.

Solutions like creating of a new popup before a request and setting the url in promise work **BUT** they are providing very **bad User experience** cause a user doesn't understand what is going on and can simple close this popup before the url would be set

Next solutions don't work for me

```
- async:false

- var popup = window.open("", '_blank');
 $.ajax(...).done(function (data) {
     popup.location.replace(data.redirectUrl);
 }
```

also all solutions there:

[stackoverflow-answers-set-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885676/open-new-tab-without-popup-blocker-after-ajax-call-on-user-click)

[stackoverflow-answers-set-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139103/open-page-in-new-window-without-popup-blocking)

[stackoverflow-answers-set-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript)

Are there any other ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explain to the user what is going on while you wait for the correct url