# AngularJS: Trying to open page in new window/tab after $http success is prevented by popup blocker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to open a window in a new tab/page after having a user submit info through an AngularJS form. However, Chrome's pop-up blocker is preventing the action.

Here's my `$http` request part in my `app.js`

```
// function to process the form
$scope.processForm = function() {
    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'docusign.php', // PHP script generates URL from form data
      data    : $scope.user  // pass in data as strings

     })
      .success(function(data) {
            window.open(data); // this gets prevented by Chrome's popup blocker
            //The root of the new page I'm trying to open is https://www.docusign.net
            // -- Am I getting a pop-up block because I'm trying to take the user to a 
            // different website?
        });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// function to process the form
$scope.processForm = function() {
    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'docusign.php', // PHP script generates URL from form data
      data    : $scope.user,  // pass in data as strings
      async   : false

     })
      .success(function(data) {
            window.open(data, '_blank'); // this gets prevented by Chrome's popup blocker
        });
};
```

Comment: It receives the same popup block issue

Comment: what is the contents of `data` it should be a string of a URL only

Comment: turns out it is due to the async nature of this call http://stackoverflow.com/a/19279442/2840591
I edited my answer to reflect this

Comment: `data` is a URL in the form of `https://www.docusign.net/member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId={someId}&Merchant-Reseller_UserName={someName}&Merchant-Reseller_Email={someEmail}`

Comment: `async: false` still has the popup block issue

Comment: To get around googles `Trusted Events` could you place the link somewhere on the page and have the user click the link?
Trusted Events - http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#trusted-events