# Spring Boot: Pass hashmap and open new page

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot

I am quite new to all web development, and I am struggling to find what I am looking for. I am using springboot.

**My expectation:**
The user will open a page, fill the form details, click on Submit button and get redirected to a new page. The form information will be stored on a hashmap and used on my backend.

**Reality:** 
The user opens the page, fill the form details, click on the Submit button but don't get redirected to a new page. Nonetheless, the information is stored on a hashmap.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" ng-app="app">
        <h1>Configurador de Plugin</h1>
            <div ng-controller = "plugins">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Database Details:</label> 
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hostname" placeholder="Informe o Endereço do Servidor" ng-model="hostname">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="port" placeholder="Informe a porta" ng-model="port">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Informe o usuário" ng-model="userdb">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userpass" placeholder="Informe a senha" ng-model="userpass">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="database" placeholder="Informe qual o banco de dados" ng-model="database">
                <button ng-click="validar()" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                <div ng-show="visivel"> 


                    <p>{{valor}}</p>
                </div>  
            </form>
            <div>Make a choice</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input ng-model="plugin.Name" value="test" type="radio" name="Test">Test</label></div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input ng-model="plugin.Name" value="v2" type="radio" name="V2">V2</label></div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input ng-model="plugin.Name" value="v1" type="radio" name="V1" >V1</label></div>
            Texto:
            <p>{{plugin.Name}}</p>
            <br>
            <button ng-click="sendForm()" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>

        </div>
    </div>
```

**The JS:**

```
app.controller('plugins', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.validar = function(){
        $scope.visivel = true;
        $scope.valor = $scope.hostname,
        console.log($scope.hostname)
    }

    $scope.enviarForm = function(){

        var url = $location.url() + "test";

        var config = 
        {
                headers : 
                {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
                }
        }
        console.log($scope.hostname);
        var data = 
        {
                hostname: $scope.hostname,
                port: $scope.port,
                username: $scope.username,
                userpass: $scope.userpass,
                database: $scope.database
        };


        $http.post(url, data, config).then(function (response) 
                {
            $scope.postResultMessage = "Sucess!";
        }, 
        function (response) {
            $scope.postResultMessage = "Fail!";
        });

    }
});
```

**The Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
    public ModelAndView CadastroEnotas(@RequestBody HashMap<String, Object> data) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("newPage");
        modelAndView.addAllObjects(data);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

So, my expectation, is that the above Controller would send the user to newPage, but it doesn't.

I am googling but I am likely misunderstanding the concept of ModelAndView or maybe how to execute the function on my js...

I think the closest to what I am looking for is described here: [angular event success when submit form it opens popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168080/angular-event-success-when-submit-form-it-opens-popup), but I failed to make it work. Could someone point me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are probably using `@Controller`, but angular post is rest request - try to define `@RestController`

Comment: I got @RestController set into it.. actually I got both annotations set to my class.

Answer (score 0):

Propably use `redirect`.

```
ModelAndView modelAndView =  new ModelAndView("redirect:/newPage.htm");
modelAndView.addAllObjects(data);
return modelAndView;
```

Or try redirect after post request: `$location.path('/newPage')`.

Check something like this: [Redirects](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward)

Comment: Thanks for trying, but didn't work, no errors but not results. The console just outputs the message: ` Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsps/newPage.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'newPage'`

Comment: In AngularJS you are using some routing? Try something like: `$location.path('/newPage')`