# can I invoke a procedure synchronously?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

This might sound a bit crazy but is there a way to call a procedure synchronously?

I am using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 and I am writing an app in javascript for the browser. I usually call my javascript adapter by:

```
WL.Client.invokeProcedure({
    adapter: 'MyAdapter',
    procedure: 'myProcedureName',
    parameters: []
}).then(function(res) {
   ...
});
```

But in this particular case I need to open another window after getting some data from the server. Since browsers will block windows when they come from async ajax my new windows does never open.

[A way to solve this would be to do the ajax request sync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20235765/149008). Is this possible with WL.Client apis? Is there a way for constructing the request manually so I can set the sync ajax flag by myself?

PS: in my case doing sync ajax request would work nice since I show a "Loading ..." view on top of everything to prevent user interaction while the request is being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WL.Client.connect() does not support `.then`.  Additionally, starting 7.0 you should use the REST API method `WLResourceRequest`: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/

Lastly, you could just put the second request in the `onSuccess` callback of the first...

Comment: Now I am using WL.Client.connect() without `.then` and I think so far it works ok. I cannot use the REST WLResourceRequest since my app is for the browser and I am using Javascript adapters. I wanted to do just a simple synchronous ajax call (no need to modify WL.Client.connect stuff) but apparently is not possible right?

Comment: After a long time...  Thanks Idan, I have realized there was no need of doing what I originally wanted (sync request). I realized this was a typical problem of javascript events, so I ended up by opening the window first and firing my request then when the request finishes I fill the new window content as needed.