# React window open disable popup on click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a component where I click and should open new window with response url, In my case I'm waiting for a response and success complete  and then hit this open link.
HOw to avoid popup browes's blocks

```
....
const generateCoPayCardTest = () => {
        if (!completed) {
            generateCoPayCard({
                patientId,
                pharmacyName
            });

            return;
        }

        openNewWindow({ url: data.copay_pdf_url });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (completed) openNewWindow({ url: data.copay_pdf_url });
    }, [completed]);

...
<LinkButton onClick={() => generateCoPayCardTest()} />
```

Also I have open window function

```
export const openNewWindow = ({ url, features = ['noopener', 'noreferrer'] }) =>
    window.open(url, '', features);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab (and not a new window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window)

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [Open page in new window without popup blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139103/open-page-in-new-window-without-popup-blocking)

You need to keep the same context from the user click event.