# How to avoid pop-up blocking when opening a new window in a different browser tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, popup-blocker

I am facing an issue when opening a URL in a different browser tab.
I have installed a pop-up blocking chrome extension.

when I click on a button to open a new URL in a new browser tab , I am getting alert saying 'popup blocking'.

I am using `window.open(URL)` for opening the new URL.

Any mechanism to avoid or bypass this issue ?

Comment: afaik, the user has to allow it

Comment: @evolutionxbox Any alternative ways for open up an URL except this mechanism.Since , non-technical persons cannot handle this.

Comment: https://www.yaplex.com/blog/avoid-browser-pop-up-blockers might have some info, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139103/open-page-in-new-window-without-popup-blocking