# Struts action should be open as popup onclick of a href link

Tags: javascript, popup, hyperlink

I have a form on my jsp,

```
<form  action="test1_action" name="test" method="post" id="test">
```

also I have two different link **link1**, **link2** here,

onclick of link1 I should submit **test1_action** action

```
$('#link1').click(function() {  
        document.forms['test'].action='test1_action';
        document.forms['test'].submit();
});
```

This works perfect for me.

what My expectation is when I click the second link **popup** should open with different action something like follows below.

```
$('#link2').click(function() {
        document.forms['test'].action='**different_action**';
        document.forms['test'].submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery so there is no need for manual DOM traversal:

```
$('#link1').click(function() {  
  $('#test').attr('action', 'test1_action').submit();
}); 

$('#link2').click(function() {  
  $('#test').attr('action', 'test2_action').submit();
});
```

The `action` attribute defines the page to which the form sends its contents, most commonly a page that interfaces with the server in some way (PHP, JSP, etc.).

What do you mean by "popup"?

Comment: I really appreciate for your responce, here I want to show as Popup window something like this. **window.open(**test2_action**,"_blank","directories=no, status=no,width=600, height=700,top=0,left=0");**

Comment: So you'd like to submit the form and open that new window *while on the same page* (without refreshing)?

Comment: Yes blendar you got it but I'd like to open as a new popup window with abouve mentioned width and height. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.open()` to open a window with a specific name, and then use that name as the target for the form submit.

```
$('#link2').click(function() {
   window.open("","test2win","directories=no,status=no,width=600,height=700,top=0,left=0");

   $('#test').attr({
     'action' : 'test2_action',
     'target' : 'test2win'
   }).submit();
});
```

I'm not sure that the above will work in all browsers though. If not, you might have to just forget the `window.open()` step and just submit the form with `target=_blank` and then set the size from within the page being returned from the submit.

Comment: **Window.open** it doesn't work, also I'm trying to set Height and width for **test2win** added Style for the page something like this <br/> html,body {<br/>
    height: 700px;
    width: 600px;<br/>} thats also sucks me... any thoughts on this.

Comment: I don't think you can change the browser window size from CSS. You need to use the `window.resizeTo()` function from JavaScript in the new page (and possibly `window.moveTo()` if you want to centre the window).

Comment: great... do you think this will work, because consider I'm working with some 10 different pages / Tabs on firefox, if I use this  **window.resizeTo()** then all other pages  would be resized right.. correct me If I'm wrong... Thanks

Comment: Some browsers ignore calls to `window.resizeTo()` if there is more than one tab open, but for those that don't: yes, it will affect all open tabs. I don't really recommend it in general, but it's there if you need it. One of the answers in the following thread uses `window.open`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178964/javascript-post-on-form-submit-open-a-new-window

Comment: No luck Mr.nnnnn.., any other thoughts would be really appreciated. Thanks