# onsubmit property fails to open new window

Tags: javascript, forms, redirect, window.open, onsubmit

A quick question here regarding forms.  I've searched the web and can't seem to figure out why what I've implemented isn't working.

The idea is simple.  I have a form inside a JSP page.  The form has an 'onsubmit' property defined to open a different jsp with some parameters.  Inside the form I have a few buttons, one of which calls a JavaScript function, which in turn submits the form (under some conditions).

Here's the code:
JSP:

```
...
<form id='testForm' onsubmit="window.open('another.jsp')">
  <input type="button" onclick="callJsFunction()" />
  ..
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function callJsFunction() {
  if (launchNow == 1) {
    var form = document.getElementById("testForm");
    form.submit();
  }
}
```

If I add target="_blank" to the form definition, a new window does open, but NOT the jsp I want to open.  Ultimately, I want the form to perform a servlet action (using the action attribute) and then open the new jsp.  Any ideas???

Thanks!

Comment: If you add `<form action="newForm.jsp" target="_blank">` newForm.jsp should open in a new window. But I can't see why you dont use a `<input type="submit" />` instead of a `button` and then have the `callJsFunction` in the `onSubmit`

Comment: Please see my comment below the proposed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to what I was looking for is found here: [Javascript Post on Form Submit open a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178964/javascript-post-on-form-submit-open-a-new-window)

Rather than setting target="_blank", I can set the target to the window I define and open.  In my servlet, I redirect to the desired jsp, and it appears in the new pop-up window.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id='testForm' action='another.jsp' target='_blank'>
```

Comment: I don't want to tie up the action parameter because I also need to invoke a servlet to do some processing.  I guess a better question is, can I redirect from a servlet to a new window?

Comment: If `action."..."` is used for something else then where's the logic that decides on what action happens when the form is submitted? As far as I can tell, you need to intercept form submission with a submit handler, do whatever is needed, possibly including an ajax call, then `return false` unconditionally to suppress natural form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but is this what you are looking for?

Please see the working demo at this link: http://fiddle.jshell.net/vf6AC/show/light/ (don't work in the jsfiddle)

```
<form action="http://google.com" id="testForm">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>​

<script type="text/javascript">
var testForm = document.getElementById("testForm");

testForm.onsubmit = function(e){
    window.open("http://stackoverflow.com");

    return true;
};​
</script>
```

See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vf6AC/

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  I found what I was looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178964/javascript-post-on-form-submit-open-a-new-window