# Attempting to call a page using POST with JavaScript, failing to pass parameters

Tags: javascript, forms

I was using the solution found here:  [Javascript Post on Form Submit open a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178964/javascript-post-on-form-submit-open-a-new-window/180999#180999)

The code I've got opens the target page as if the submit worked properly.  When I look at the form itself, all of the hidden fields are there, but the target doesn't see them - $_REQUEST is empty in the PHP code.  Here's my function to create the view (heavily stolen from the post mentioned above):

```
    function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
        method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", method);
        form.setAttribute("action", path);
        form.setAttribute("target", "formresult");

        for(var key in params) {
            if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
                hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
            }
        }
        document.body.appendChild(form);

        window.open("", "formresult", '');

        form.submit();

        document.body.removeChild(form);
    }
```

And here is the call:

```
    post_to_url("test.php", { "username": "shaleth", "action": "login" }, "post");
```

I have to be missing something simple, but I can't see it.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Some keys on `$_REQUEST` can be overriden by cookies, environment variables, and others. Did you check `$_POST`?

Comment: I checked both - both were empty.  :/

Comment: OK, I was right - it was something simple (read: stupid).  Not obvious from the "cleansed" code above, but I was doing a cross-domain request.  Testing the code against a local php script works flawlessly.  Now to "fix" the remote code...