# Form submit open in new window modal

Tags: javascript, forms

What I need to do is when the form was submit it opens in new window modal. I got this script in [Javascript Post on Form Submit open a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178964/javascript-post-on-form-submit-open-a-new-window). When I try to submit the form it isn't working. Any help will appreciate.

**Index.php**

```
<form id="formprint" name="formprint">
<input type="text" name="search" id="search">
<input type="submit" name="print" value="print"/>
</form>

<script>
var form = document.getElementById("formprint");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", "print.php");

// setting form target to a window named 'formresult'
form.setAttribute("target", "formresult");

var textField = document.getElementById("search");              
textField.setAttribute("name", "search");
form.appendChild(textField);
document.body.appendChild(form);

// creating the 'formresult' window with custom features prior to submitting the form
window.open(../print.php, 'formresult', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');

form.submit();
</script>
```

**Print.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['print'])) {
$search = $_POST['search'];
}
?>
```

Comment: you are running the script before the document is ready to be used

Comment: @PatrickEvans it also the same even I put the script below the elements.

Comment: then you need to edit your question to expand on what isn't working. As you do not explain at all what problems you are having.