# Open new Tab or Window with POST [PHP]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**This is the situation:** I have 2 files, **reportCaller.php** and **report.php**. From the reportCaller.php, the user is going to press a button with the method "onclick", this will call the function that is going to do the ajax/post stuff (this is with what im having problems), report.php is going to catch some parameters by POST and has to be opened on a new Tab or Window, this is going to display a report. (Note: *May be not important, but im using HTML2PDF*).

reportCaller (HTML):

```
<input type="button" onclick="generateReport()">
```

reportCaller (JS):

```
function generateReport(){

  var id = '¡I must reach the report FILE!';
  //I tried a couple stuff, but didnt work, this is one:
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "report.php",
        data: {id:id},
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            myWindow = window.open(encodeURIComponent(true),
                "_blank");
            myWindow.focus();
    });

}
```

report:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
//This file (report.php) must catch $_POST, will not help if i only open the file in a new Tab/Window
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: show us what you have tried. Its hard to understand what you are trying / doing based on what you have provided.

Comment: If the answer provided doesn't help. Try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: I know how to open urls in new tabs and windows. The problem is that i need to send data throught post method to that url.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Is your ajax call not working properly?

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but I haven't got the reputation ;-)

take a look at 
[Javascript Post on Form Submit open a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178964/javascript-post-on-form-submit-open-a-new-window)

the trick is to put your button in a

```
<form target="_blank">
```

Element and then send that form..

You could do your processing of data in the onsubmit Handler

Comment: if you had asked some questions I would have upvoted to get you to 50