# Submit a form open new browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

i have a form to submit like this

```
<form role="form" action="{{ url('panel/print/direport') }}" id="printForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="dfno" value="{{ $dfno }}" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="bonperiod" value="{{ $bonperiod }}" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="bonstuck" value="{{ $bonstuck }}" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="boninc" value="{{ $boninc }}" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="userids" value="{{ $userids }}" class="form-control">
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('printForm').submit();" class="btn btn-primary">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i>&nbsp; Print</button>
```

usually if we want to the form submit to open new tab we just need to add `target="_blank"`, my question is how to open new browser window when i click the button submit form?

Comment: simply here you can also write target="_blank"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Post on Form Submit open a new window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178964/javascript-post-on-form-submit-open-a-new-window)

Answer (score 0):

please try like this with js

```
$('.btn-primary').click(function () {
   var url="http://www.yoursite.com";
   window.open(url,'NewWindow','width=600,height=600');
});
```

Comment: how to specify the width and height so it can go full screen size?

Comment: @Wallflower we can eight er specify width and height like in the above example . for full screen you need to specify fuulscreen=true , 

 **window.open(url,'NewWindow','fullscreen=true');**

like this

Comment: its not equal `true` but `yes` or `1` if u want to go fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

Two Way I Given Here

```
<form action="..." ...
onsubmit="window.open('google.html', '_blank', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');return true;">
```

Also We can Use

```
<form target="_blank" action="http://example.com"
  method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form"
  name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate">
```

Comment: I've seen this answer before

Comment: @Samudrala Ramu how to specify the width and height so it can go full screen size?

Comment: function OpenWindow() {
        window.open('../ReportWebForm.aspx?ReportType=Report','', 'width = 100, height = 100');
    }

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by`window.open` method when you give `height` and `width` attribute to it

Refer the link for detail information
[JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)